# Property 'path' does not exist on type 'Router' , in angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript

i am new in Angular 2  and creating a demo app. I got this error while doing same.I think I am doing something wrong in below code:

```
  canLoad(router: Router): boolean {
      let url = `/${router.path}`;
      return this.checkLogin(url);
    }
```

Please suggest me,  what I am doing wrong? In the above code I think, `path` is not a property of `router` that is I know but what is the correct property for the same?

**Complete code -**

```
import { Injectable }       from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate, Router,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  CanActivateChild,
  NavigationExtras,CanLoad
}                           from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService }      from './auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild,CanLoad {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url: string = state.url;

    return this.checkLogin(url);
  }

  canActivateChild(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    return this.canActivate(route, state);
  }


  canLoad(router: Router): boolean {
  let url = `/${router.path}`;
  return this.checkLogin(url);
}

  checkLogin(url: string): boolean {
    if (this.authService.isLoggedIn) { return true; }

    // Store the attempted URL for redirecting
    this.authService.redirectUrl = url;

    // Create a dummy session id
    let sessionId = 123456789;

    // Set our navigation extras object
    // that contains our global query params and fragment
    let navigationExtras: NavigationExtras = {
      queryParams: { 'shubhamsession_id': sessionId },
      fragment: 'shubhamanchor'
    };

    // Navigate to the login page with extras
    this.router.navigate(['/login'], navigationExtras);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the url, inject `RouterStateSnapshot` instead of the `Router`:

```
canLoad(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    let url = state.url;
    return this.checkLogin(url);
}
```

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html

Comment: Thanks @Seidme, But when I console, console.log(router); then path is showing on console but when I console,  console.log(router.url); then this is showing undefined. Why this ?

Though, path is a property and url is not a property. Then why its going on ?

Comment: Not sure what's happening there, but an adopted way to achieve what you want would be to inject ActivatedRouteSnapshot or RouterStateSnapshot: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html